# Finding the principal disjunctive normal form (PDNF) of a Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Find the principal disjunctive normal form (PDNF) of a Boolean expression 
$$((p\wedge q) \rightarrow r)\vee((p\wedge q)\rightarrow \neg r).$$
I  tried by expanding it but I am stuck with the expression 
$(\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r) \vee (\neg p \vee \neg q \vee \neg r)$. I don't know how to convert them into min terms. Please help me.

Comment: Your last expression can be written as $\text{Something}\lor (r\lor \neg r)$.

Comment: First you must see that either the equation is sum of products or not.As it has only disjunctions, so it is not possible to find DNF for this equation.

Answer (score 4):

Expression mentioned is a Tautology.
$$((p.q) \rightarrow r)+((p.q)\rightarrow r')=((p'+q'+r)+(p'+q'+r'))=p'+q'+1 = 1$$
So PDNF corresponding to it is 
$$(p'.q'.r')+(p'.q'.r)+(p'.q.r')+(p'.q.r)+(p.q'.r')+(p.q'.r)+(p.q.r')+(p.q.r)$$

Answer (score -1):

The required normal form is ( if I am not wrong ):-

**(p^q^r)v(~p^q^r)v(~p^~q^r)v(p^q^~r)**

Once you get the form : (¬p∨¬q∨r)∨(¬p∨¬q∨¬r)
Treat this as (¬p)∨(¬q)∨(r)∨(¬p)∨(¬q)∨(¬r)
And convert the individual literals into minterms.

To convert any variable P to a minterm ,just add :  ^(Qv~Q)^(Rv~R)  to P
That is :P^(Qv~Q)^(Rv~R)
And then use the distributive laws.